# MYSQL query - Counting Values in columns dynamically

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query to pull a certain set of results. While doing that I want to be able to keep a count of number of occurrences of a certain value in a certain field. I'm trying to pull a record of part-numbers from a table for devices, There are various partnumbers that are pulled from tables.

For instance this is my result set

```
CISCO1841
CISCO2610
CISCO2650 
CISCO2610
CISCO2650
CISCO2500
```

I should keep track that

`CISCO1841` occured one time, `CISCO2610` occured twice, `CISCO2650` occured twice and `CISCO2500` occured once. I need to store this count and set another column value based on this count. Is there an efficient way to do this in MYSQL?

Comment: SQL has a function COUNT() , you should check it out.

Answer (score 1):

*Group* your query and *`COUNT()`* the results:

```
SELECT myColumn, COUNT(*) FROM myTable GROUP BY myColumn
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f2f33/1/0).

Comment: I'm trying to count dynamically, not from a table.

Comment: @user2413942: So adapt accordingly.  Without further information, I fail to see how anyone can give a more complete answer.

Comment: Sorry. Basically this is my query

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) on the table where your data is inserted and that trigger will keep count of the occurrences by updating the counter for each word (ex : CISCO2650) in a separate table.

Or you can try a query like below but its not dynamic :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(M_PART_NBR = 'CISCO2610',1,0)) as NBR1, 
    SUM(IF(M_PART_NBR = 'CISCO2811',1,0)) as NBR2,
    SUM(IF(M_PART_NBR = 'CISCO2911',1,0)) as NBR3
FROM 
    C2_INST_PRODUCT WHERE M_PART_NBR LIKE '%CISCO2%'
```

Comment: SELECT M_PART_NBR FROM C2_INST_PRODUCT
WHERE M_PART_NBR LIKE '%CISCO2%'

"CISCO2610"
"CISCO2811"
"CISCO2911/K9"
"CISCO2911/K9"

I need TO COUNT the occurences AND store the COUNT IN a variable.